# PHP How to show db tables based on a column value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script to echo the name of db tables present in a db, but now I want to only echo those to the users who are recorded in the tables.

Here is my current script:

```
        if ( !$conn ) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $tablesquerys = "SHOW TABLES";

    $tableresults = mysqli_query($conn, $tablesquerys) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    if ( mysqli_num_rows($tableresults) > 0 ) {

        echo "<select id='dbtable_selector' class='dbtable-selector'>";
        echo "<option value='Current Tables' selected='selected'>Current Files</option>";

        while( $table = mysqli_fetch_array($tableresults, MYSQLI_NUM) ) {
            echo("<option value='" . $table[0] . "'>" . $table[0] . "</option>");
        }

        echo "</select>";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
```

The username to compare against is store in `$currentuser`

My 2nd attempt:

```
    if ( !$conn ) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $tablesquerys = "SHOW TABLES";

    $tableresults = mysqli_query($conn, $tablesquerys) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    if ( mysqli_num_rows($tableresults) > 0 ) {

        echo "<select id='dbtable_selector' class='dbtable-selector'>";
        echo "<option value='Current Tables' selected='selected'>Current Files</option>";

        while( $table = mysqli_fetch_array($tableresults, MYSQLI_NUM) ) {
            $userquerys = "SELECT username FROM `" . $table[0] . "`";

            if ( mysqli_query($conn, $userquerys) ) {
                if ( $userquerys === $currentuser ) {
                    echo("<option value='" . $table[0] . "'>" . $table[0] . "</option>");
                }
            } else {
                echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        }

        echo "</select>";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Still nothing echoed or any errors.

Ok I see the flaw in the attempt above so here is my 3rd attempt:

```
        if ( !$conn ) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $tablesquerys = "SHOW TABLES";

    $tableresults = mysqli_query($conn, $tablesquerys) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    if ( mysqli_num_rows($tableresults) > 0 ) {

        echo "<select id='dbtable_selector' class='dbtable-selector'>";
        echo "<option value='Current Tables' selected='selected'>Current Files</option>";

        while( $table = mysqli_fetch_array($tableresults, MYSQLI_NUM) ) {
            $userquerys = "SELECT username FROM `" . $table[0] . "`";

                if ( mysqli_query($conn, $userquerys) === $currentuser ) {
                    echo("<option value='" . $table[0] . "'>" . $table[0] . "</option>");
                }
        }

        echo "</select>";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Still nothing.

Comment: exactly where are you defining `$userquerys`? and what's the point of building a full query string and comparing it against some other query string? wouldn't it be easier/more efficient to do `if ($table[0] == $username)` directly? if you want to check if some username is in $table[0], then you're not executing the query at all - you're just defining a string with some sql in it.

Comment: Fair point, I was getting ahead of my self. I will post current script above.